# How to delete the last character in a string (without using init) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm really new to Haskell programming. Can anyone help with this issues?
-- delete the last character from a string in Haskell

```
deleteLast []     = "Empty list!" -- if the string is enpty 
deleteLast (h:[]) = h  -- recursion
deleteLast (h:t)  = deleteLast t -- found the last character
result1 = [x | x == deleteLast , x /= deleteLast t] -- trying to remove the last character found 
                                                       from the string
```

Comment: Think about what `deleteLast "a"` should be. This is the same of `deleteLast ('a':[])`, so you have to fix the line `deleteLast (h:[]) = h`. That's not all you have to do, but it's a start.

Comment: Also, see what happens if the input is `"Empty list!!"`, the caller will not be able to distinguish the error from the correct result. Use the [`error`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:error) function or the [`Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either) type as return value.

Comment: The initial title of the question could have mislead users into thinking one had to determine whether an input character was a *letter* or not, using for example library function [isLetter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isLetter).

Comment: Why can't you use `init`? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, cannot use any predefined function in haskell

Comment: For future q's: your sample code could not have compiled. Give the error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of the `deleteLast` is the same type as the *item* of the list. Indeed, the second clause specfies:

```
deleteLast (h:[]) = h
```

here `h` is the *head* of the list, and thus the first item. The pattern `(h:[])` is equivalent to `[h]`, so this fires if there is a list with one element. In that case we return that singe element.

In case a list contains one element, we have to remove that element from the list (1). If we work with a list with at least two elements, we should yield the first item of that list, and recurse on the tail of the list:

```
deleteLast :: [a] -> [a]
deleteLast [] = error "Empty list!"
deleteLast [h] = …  -- (1)
deleteLast (h:t) = … deleteLast t  -- (2)
```

I leave implementing the second and third clause as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

```
myLast :: [a] -> [a]
myLast []     = error "Empty list!"
myLast [h]    = []
myLast (h:t)  =[h]++myLast t

Output:
ghci> myLast "pineapple"
"pineappl"
ghci> myLast "pen"
"pe"
```

Thanks for the tips. @William Van Onsem

Comment: Good ! But your last clause is neater when written as `myLast (h:t)  = h : (myLast  t)`

Comment: You can leave out the parens: `myLast (h:t) = h : myLast t`.